# Automorphism of Field Extension Statement

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

In our Galois Theory course the following statement was given to us in lectures:

> Suppose that $L : K$ is ﬁnite and normal, and $α, β ∈ L$ are roots of
>   an irreducible polynomial $m ∈ K[x]$. Then there exists an
>   automorphism $σ ∈ \text{Aut}(L)$ with $σ(α) = β$ and $σ_{| K} =
>  \text{id}_K$ .

I want to see how this can be proven.

I think we need to use a result about extending the inclusion $K \longrightarrow L$ to some map $K(\alpha) \longrightarrow L$ [ we have been introduced to a theorem about extending monomorphisms to simple extensions]. We discussed the statement a little after class and it was suggested then we should then argue using the uniqueness of the splitting field for a given polynonmial, though I can't see how.

If someone could outline a proof, that would be very useful for me. Thanks.